# Conexión SQL Server y C# en Aplicación Multi-Hilos

Tags: c#, sql-server, configuración

Tengo una clase para manejar la conexión de `Sql` y `C#` la cual contiene varios métodos:

Método para **obtener la cadena de conexión** desde un `ArchivoConexion.ini` :

[image: Archivo de Conexión]

```
 private string obtener_cadena_conexion()
 {
     string nombre_seccion = "Conexion";

     string ruta_archivo = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\ArchivoConexion.ini";

      string cadena = string.Empty;

      if (File.Exists(ruta_archivo))
     {
        cadena = "Data Source=" + obtener_valor_clave(ruta_archivo, nombre_seccion, "Servidor", "") +
                        ";Initial Catalog=" + obtener_valor_clave(ruta_archivo, nombre_seccion, "Base de Datos", "") +
                        ";Integrated Security=SSPI;";
     }
     return cadena;
 }
```

> He obviado la función : `obtener_valor_clave` porque no contribuye a la resolución de la pregunta.

Método para **Abrir la Conexón:**

```
public SqlConnection sql_conexion;

public SqlConnection abrir_conexion()
        {
            if (sql_conexion.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                try
                {
                    sql_conexion.ConnectionString = cadena_conexion;
                    sql_conexion.Open();
                }
                catch (SqlException excepcion)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error conectandose a la Base de Datos. + excepcion.Message,
                     "ERROR CONEXIÓN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            return sql_conexion;
        }
```

Método para **Cerrar la Conexión**

```
 public void cerrar_conexion()
        {
            if (sql_conexion.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                try
                {
                    sql_conexion.Close();
                }
                catch (SqlException excepcion)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error  al cerrar la conexión con la Base de Datos. + excepcion.Message,
                     "ERROR DE CONEXIÓN", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
```

Todo esta perfecto obtengo la conexión correctamente, el **PROBLEMA** es que al esta ser una conexión global si deseo ejecutar una aplicación multi-hilos utilizando la misma conexión en ambos hilos, explotará esta estructura de conexión.

> Si ambos hilos se están ejecutando y un hilo acaba primero cerrará la conexión y como el otro método no ha terminado y la conexión se cerró causará un enorme problema.

**¿Cómo puedo crear un método de conexión no global que funcione para una aplicación multi-hilos?**

Comment: Porque usas una sola conexion? lo correcto seria que cada hilo (es mas, que cada transaccion a la base de datos) abriera y cerrara la conexion a la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para separarlas?

Comment: No entiendo lo que prfguntas. Cada transaccion abre y cierra su conexion

Comment: @gbianchi en cada proceso yo invoco el método que abre la conexión y cuando termina la ejecución invoco el método que cierra la conexión. Pero en caso que sea multi-hilos habrá problemas. **¿Cuál sería una forma correcta de implementar las  conexiones?**

Comment: No debe ser un objeto global. Debe ser una clase conexion que instancias en cada caso y ese mantiene viva cada conexion. Igual todo esto depende mucho de la arquitectura del sistema

Comment: Pero **estos métodos los tengo en una clase**, no comprendo entonces de que otra forma es. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberias de crear una conexion por hilos y asi evitar errores de acceso a memoria que puede que este en uso o posiblemente no existan o donde la conexion este cerrada.

Crea un metodo donde cree siempre una nueva instancia de la conexion a base de datos y asi siempre que lo necesites en un hilo, lo llamas y listo:

```
public SqlConnection crear_conexion()
{
    SqlConnection sql_conexion = new SqlConnection(cadena_conexion);
    sql_conexion.Open();

    return sql_conexion;
}
```

Su uso seria:

```
using(var conexion = crear_conexion())
{
   // aqui consultas 
}
```

Comment: Prácticamente el método es igual a mi método de `abrir conexion` , lo que veo es que se crea la conexión directamente dentro del método **crear_conexion**  aqui: `SqlConnection sql_conexion = new SqlConnection(cadena_conexion);`  :)